# Python webdriver manager, ValueError API Rate Limit Exceeded Use GH_TOKEN

Tags: python, python-3.x, geckodriver, webdrivermanager-python

I am facing an issue with webdriver-manager, for Firefox.

This is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager



driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://google.com")
time.sleep(5)
```

I am running into this issue.

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current firefox version is 101.0
[WDM] - Get LATEST geckodriver version for 101.0 firefox
[WDM] - GH_TOKEN will be used to perform requests
ValueError: API Rate limit exceeded. You have to add GH_TOKEN!!!
```

I have gone through a bunch of videos on YouTube where people use webdriver_manager for Firefox but none of them even encounter this error, they also do not mention the use of any GH-Token.

I don't want to use a GH_Token.

How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Creating a token in GitHub.

1. In the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click **Settings**.
2. In the left sidebar, click <> **Developer settings**.
3. In the left sidebar, click **Personal access tokens**.
4. Click **Generate new token**.
5. Give your token a descriptive name.
6. To give your token an expiration, select the Expiration drop-down menu, then click a default or use the calendar picker.
7. Select the scopes or permissions, you'd like to grant this token. To use your token to access repositories from the command line, select repo.
8. Click Generate token.

**Configuration**

import os

os.environ['GH_TOKEN'] = "paste Generate token "

Comment: I have very specifically mentioned that I dont want GitHub Tokens

Comment: I know you said you don't want to use a GH token, but you can create one that never expires and set it to only have public_repo scope.  That will have no scope over anything except repos which are already publicly accessible on the internet.